# Implement slide animation of view when model changes in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have several cards with translations of word. `ChooseTrainingView` is my view which get word as model and success handler. When I click on translation it changes `training.currentWord` so I expect animation between two views. First view should slide to left and then second view shows from right with slide. But my code below has strange behaviour:

```
    Group {
        ForEach(training.words) { w in
            if w == training.currentWord {
                ChooseTrainingView(word: training.currentWord) { success in
                    withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5)) {
                        _ = training.goToNext(success: success)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .transition(.slide)
```

[image: Result of code]

Animation has only a part of views to be animated and only in view appearing. There is no disappearing view animation.

I tried to not use `ForEach`, but I cannot understand how to animate full view when I change `currentWord` - the view just change word at top and safe its state instead of creating new view with new values from `currentWord`

Also I cannot find examples how to animate sliding right-to-left views by replacing the model for view

Comment: Please show a [mcve] - something I can copy and paste into a new Xcode project and reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @J W answer I found the solution. We should to add `.id` modifier to our view. Besides we don't need `ForEach` anymore and it means that we don't need to use array of `words`. Just one `word` (which conforms to `Identifiable`) and when we change this `word` our view will be fully recreated (reset its state). There is a code with the solution:

```
Group {
    ChooseTrainingView(word: training.currentWord) { success in
        withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5)) {
            _ = training.goToNext(success: success)
        }
    }
    .id(training.currentWord.id)
}
.transition(.slide)
```

In addition, I found very good article which explains how `.id` modifier works:

https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-id/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the `animation`, it's very easy ୧(๑•̀⌄•́๑)૭

change the `.transition(.slide)` to `.transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading), removal: .move(edge: .trailing)))`

[image: Showing Image]

If there is any other problem, please refer to the following content. If it really doesn’t work, please feel free to ask me again.

Example Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ChooseTrainingView: View {
  var word: String
  var successHandler: (Bool) -> Void

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
        .shadow(radius: 10)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
      
      VStack {
        HStack {
          Text(word)
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
          Image(systemName: "speaker.wave.2")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        
        Divider().background(Color.white)
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
          ForEach(0..<5) { index in
            Text("Option \(index)")
              .padding(.vertical, 8)
              .padding(.horizontal)
              .foregroundColor(.white)
              .cornerRadius(10)
          }
        }
        .padding()
      }
      .padding()
    }
    .onTapGesture {
      self.successHandler(true)
      print("successHandler")
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var training = TrainingModel(words: (0...5).map{Word(translation: String($0))})
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      ForEach(training.words, id: \.self) { word in
        if word == training.words[training.currentWordIndex] {
          ChooseTrainingView(word: word.translation, successHandler: { success in
            withAnimation {
              _ = training.goToNext(success: success)
            }
          })
          .id(word.id)
          .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading), removal: .move(edge: .trailing)))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct Word: Hashable, Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  var translation: String
}

class TrainingModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var words: [Word]
  @Published var currentWordIndex: Int
  
  init(words: [Word]) {
    self.words = words
    self.currentWordIndex = 0
  }
  
  func goToNext(success: Bool) -> Bool {
    if currentWordIndex < words.count - 1 {
      currentWordIndex += 1
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Changing of `.transition` modifier have no effect. But when I add `.id` modifier it works! Besides there is no sense to add `ForEach`, it works with just one view